# Nodejs REST resouce not "reusable" to start mocha tests programmatically

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I started to use mocha programmatically, which means I run the test suite every time when I request the resouce `localhost:3000/tests/start`.

```js
app.get('/tests/start', (req, res) => {
  var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'json'
  });

  mocha.useColors(false);
  config.tests.forEach(test => {
    if(test.enabled) 
      mocha.addFile('./test/cases/' + test.filename + '.js')
  });

  mocha.run(function(failures){
    console.log(failures);
    res.send();
  });
});
```

If I start node and call `localhost:3000/tests/start` everything works fine and my tests pass.
But when I call the same resouce later again, I get only that feedback:

```
{
  "stats": {
    "suites": 0,
    "tests": 0,
    "passes": 0,
    "pending": 0,
    "failures": 0,
    "start": "2017-04-10T14:54:14.322Z",
    "end": "2017-04-10T14:54:14.322Z",
    "duration": 0
  },
  "tests": [],
  "pending": [],
  "failures": [],
  "passes": []
}
```

I thought REST is stateles... Do anyone know more about this "issue" or a good way to debug my application? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know , it looks like mocha is doing everything that you tell it do. btw why are you running your test cases like this?

Comment: Yes exactly for the first call everything works fine. But then I need to restart the node process to reproduce the first "pass" output otherwise the suite would be empty (like in my output above). "I" call the tests like this, because another tool needs to run (a part of) those tests (sometimes).

Comment: you need to setup your tests in better way you can work with child_process module to run all tests and output the result which in turn are send to http response. You can tell mocha to run hooks before/after.. i believe you can achieve better result that way. Also try to look for cache headers that are send to client try disabling them  so client can get fresh results each time.